Pinescript - looping through tickers and asset values for the currently selected chart's symbol
I am trying to calculate AssetValue for the currently selected chart's symbol, and I'm stuck on looping through the tickers and asset values. Any suggestions on how to loop through them?
This is my code:
// Assets for tickers
ticker1 = input.symbol("KUCOIN:BTCUSDT", title="1", inline = "1", group = "Tickers / Assets")
ticker2 = input.symbol("BINANCE:ETHUSDT", title="2", inline = "2", group = "Tickers / Assets")
// (other 7 tickers)

asset1 = input.float(10, title = "", inline = "1", group = "Tickers / Assets")
asset2 = input.float(10, title = "", inline = "2", group = "Tickers / Assets")
// (other 7 asset values)

AssetTableOn = input(true,"Show Asset Table")
ticker = syminfo.ticker
prefix = syminfo.prefix
fullticker = prefix + ":" + ticker

// Loop through all tickers and corresponding assets
for i = 1 to 9
    currentTicker = ticker(i)
    currentAsset = asset(1)
    if (fullticker == currentTicker)
        Assets = currentAsset
        AssetValue = currentAsset * close
        break

AssetStr = str.tostring(Assets, '#,###.##')
AssetValueStr = str.tostring(AssetValue, '#,###.##')

if (AssetTableOn == true)
    // create table


I fixed this using multiple if statements instead of a loop.
